# Using Javascript to smoothly slide up a div to height of 0 pixels

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 radio buttons, one of which will be pre-selected when the page loads. If 'yes' is already checked, a div will have a height of 100%, if 'no', the height should be 0px (making it invisible). If the user then checks the other button, the div will either slide up or down, to be visible or not.

This all works fine, except in the case when 'yes' is pre-checked - the div is correctly visible on page load, but when 'no' is clicked, the div just vanishes (rather than sliding smoothly). However, if the buttons are then clicked after that, it works as intended.

I have recreated this in [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnrstdho/30/), the effect is the same (although I'm not sure why the text is still visible), the first time 'no' is clicked the div jumps, but after that it works as desired.

This is my html:

```
<input id='editpositive' class='form__radio-input' type='radio' name='subgroupEdit' value='editpositive' checked=checked/>
     <label class='form__radio-label' for='editpositive'>
        <span class='form__radio-button'></span>Yes</label>
<input id='editnegative' class='form__radio-input' type='radio' name='subgroupEdit' value='editnegative'/>
    <label class='form__radio-label' for='editnegative'>
       <span class='form__radio-button'></span>No</label>
         <div class='subgroupEdit-accordion-show'>
           STUFF GOES HERE
         </div>
```

css:

```
.subgroupEdit-accordion-show {
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    height: 100%;
 }
```

js:

```
const slideDown = element => element.style.height = `${element.scrollHeight}px`
const slideUp = element => element.style.height = `0px`
document.getElementById('editpositive').addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
    slideDown(document.querySelector('.subgroupEdit-accordion-show'))
     })

document.getElementById('editnegative').addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
   slideUp(document.querySelector('.subgroupEdit-accordion-show'))
    })
```

How do I make the div slide up smoothly to 0px height when the div is initially visible on page load?

Comment: I would do this with CSS only, using `:checked` and `transition`. Simpler than the javascript approach

Comment: I need to clear out some values as well - I think I have to do this with js.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, you need to give it a fixed height or else it won't work properly the first time.

Try with this CSS

```
.subgroupEdit-accordion-show {
  transition: height 0.5s ease-out;
  height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Although that does work in my jsfiddle, it doesn't in my original code for some reason, and also, this sets the height on load at 15px (obviously), which is not the same height as if you click the button again (it's less bunched up), so I would have to figure out the correct number of px, rather than just have it as a nice responsive '100%'. Thanks for the answer though, it got me closer......